# load corresponding divs in separate areas randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

I have a webpage that requires I load corresponding divs (meaning they share the same information) in two different areas. This is similar to how multiple banner ads of the same ad campaign load all over a webpage, and when you hit refresh it's a different advertisement (One moment your page is full of Toyota Ads, on refresh you're seeing different instances of Adobe).

Right now, I'm successfully loading one of three random divs. I have them in unordered lists because there are divs in my divs.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<ul id="reps">
    <li>
        <div class="contact1">
        ...
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="contact2">
        ...
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="contact3">
        ...
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and the script here, which is working form me:

```
    // random rep
    this.randomtip = function(){
        var length = $("#reps li").length;
        var ran = Math.floor(Math.random()*length) + 1;
        $("#reps li:nth-child(" + ran + ")").show();
    };

    $(document).ready(function(){    
        $('#reps li').hide();
        randomtip();
    });
```

Now I need to replicate this, and have the second set of divs correspond to which ever the one above does. Maybe I need to use PHP? Not sure... Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do something like this, kinda recursive:

http://jsfiddle.net/sanpopo/Hq8KC/

```
randomtip = function (randNum, el) {
    var length = el.length, ran;    
    if (randNum === "") {
    ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * length);  
    } else {
        ran = randNum;
    }    
    $(el.eq(ran)).show();     
    return ran;    
};
```

Comment: Exactly what I am trying to do. Much appreciated!!

Comment: Quick question. How can i initiate this on page load, rather than a button click? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sanpopo/Hq8KC/ basically just call the randomDiv() function from inside document.ready

Comment: Thank you Sanpopo. Solved a lot of headaches for me today.

Comment: Sanpopo, this is working for two separate instances, but what if there were 3 or more?

Comment: you would just next another function like so: http://jsfiddle.net/sanpopo/Hq8KC/ however, if you are going have more than 4 it might start to look really confusing and another route may be necessary

Comment: Thanks. I swear I tried that. Must have had an error. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have another list of divs on the page with the ID "reps2", for example, you can hide/show the elements you want all at once by comma-separating different selectors:

```
$('#reps li,#reps2 li').hide();
```

...

```
$("#reps li:nth-child(" + ran + "),#reps2 li:nth-child(" + ran + ")").show();
```

Alternately, you can use `.add()`

```
$('#reps li').add('#reps2 li').hide();
```